# Problem In Recycler View Grid Layout Manager,

Tags: android, gridlayoutmanager

I have created a grid layout Like this:

[image: I have created A Grid Layout Like this]

But I want my grid layout some thing like this:

[image: But I Want My grid Layout some thing like this]

I want my text to be appear on right side. Like Contacts List. Please tell me what changes I must have to do in my layout file. Waiting for a good response.

Comment: Thanks @TrebuchetMs for correcting me...

Comment: No worries, part of the moderation process. I can forsee downvotes going your way due to [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). I suggest you [copy-paste your code into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53466860/edit) and [format it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to make it presentable. :-)

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Sorry for inconvenience, i am new to stack overflow. And this is my first question. So i am not much familiar with rules & regulations of stack overflow. Next time will keep this in mind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this the xml code just copy and past

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/android_list_view_tutorial_with_example"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pic1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YOUR TEXT"
    android:id="@+id/album_title">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks u so much @Abdomns. This really solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want a list and not a grid, you should use a LinearLayoutManager, not a GridLayoutManager.

See the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the orientation of your linerlayout to horizontal.